# How can I code to retain the data even after its closed?

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, serialization, deserialization

I'm relatively new to c# and winforms,I need some coding assistance to solve the problem.
I had created an winform with 4 text box and using an save button i had serialized those data in xml .the actual problem is: how to deserialize the data ,in that the items get back to their respective text boxes. and if i closed and opened the entire application the data in the textboxes should get retained.

objective : How to make the data retain in the application(textboxes) even after its closed and opened again. here i am not supposed to use any database

Comment: Save xml in .xml file, then read and deserialize xml into the object.

Comment: You need to map the text box names to the xml tags.  Simplest way is to make the xml tag names the same as the text box names.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to accomplish that is by binding the data to an Application Settings variable.

1. Bind each textbox to its own Application Settings variable, taking care to create them as User scoped (the default), rather than Application scope.
2. Register a Form_Closing event handler, and have it save the settings.

Following is the Form_Closing event routine from a production C# program that I wrote in 2005, and use daily.

```
private void frmMain_FormClosing ( object sender , FormClosingEventArgs e )
{   // Update user settings, even if the cmdQuit_Click event was bypassed.
    if ( _intDesiredWidth > STRING_IS_EMPTY )
    {
        int intDefaultDesiredWidth;

        if ( int.TryParse ( Properties.Settings.Default.DesiredWidth , out intDefaultDesiredWidth ) )
        {
            if ( _intDesiredWidth != intDefaultDesiredWidth )
            {
                Properties.Settings.Default.DesiredWidth = _intDesiredWidth.ToString ( );
                Properties.Settings.Default.Save ( );   // Save only when there is something worth saving.
            }   // if ( _intDesiredWidth != intDefaultDesiredWidth )
        }   // if ( int.TryParse ( Properties.Settings.Default.DesiredWidth , out intDefaultDesiredWidth ) )
    }   // if ( _intDesiredWidth > STRING_IS_EMPTY )
}   // private void frmMain_FormClosing
```

Comment: That is definitely not the only way.